# ngrx Component store with angular, get observable with values from effect?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-component-store, component-store

I try to do a custom autocomplete component in my angular 16 project.
That component should be able to lazy fetch the data from my component store.

I achieve to do something like that :

```ts
 // MySearchComponent
  @Input({ required: true }) searchValues$?: Observable<SearchInputObject[]>;

  @Input({ required: true }) searchValuesSubscription!: any;// the trigger

  @Input({ required: true }) fieldCtrl!: FormControl<SearchInputObject | null>; // form control to return the selected value
```

With `searchValuesSubscription` a trigger of my effect, and `searchValues$` the select associated in the store.

I find that solution not very developper friendly, as if I use the component 10 times, I'll have to create those 2 properties in the parent component to use MySearchComponent

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.searchValues$ = this._myStore.companyCategories$;
  this.searchValuesSubscription$ = this._myStore.loadCompanyCategories;
}
```

And to call the component :

```ts
<app-async-search-input
  [fieldCtrl]="docCategoryCtrl"
  [searchValues$]="searchValues$"            
  [searchValuesSubscription]="searchValuesSubscription$">
</app-async-search-input>
```

An extract of the Effect, just in case it helps :)

```ts
 readonly loadCompanyCategories = this.effect<void>(trigger$ =>
    trigger$.pipe(
      exhaustMap(() =>
        combineLatest([this.userInstance$, this.selectedCompanyId$]).pipe(
          switchMap(([instance, selectedCompanyId]) => {
            if (instance && selectedCompanyId) {
              return this._apiService.getCompanyCategories(instance, selectedCompanyId).pipe(
                tapResponse(
                  companiesCategories => {
                    this.patchState({
                      nonPersistent: {
                        ...this.get().nonPersistent,
                        companyCategories: companiesCategories,
                      },
                    });
                  },
                  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => console.error(error)
                )
              );
            }
            return [];
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Here a stackblitz that show a simplified version of what I did : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-frdx5b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fasync-autocomplete%2Fasync-autocomplete.component.ts
You need to click on "Load books" so the AsyncAutocompleteComponent trigger the store, and then display the list of book in a select.

Is there a way to have a trigger that return on observable of the values ? Or is it something that shouldn't be done with an Effect ? Is there another way to do that ?
I'm open to all advice !
Thanks !

Comment: Passing observables and subscriptions as inputs into other components is an anti-pattern. It would help if you posted more of the code before I attempt to really answer your question or give advice. Creating a stackblitz (or similar) would be even better.

Comment: Thanks you @Geo242, I edited my post, hope the stackblitz is enough :) 
Here a stackblitz that show a simplified version of what I did : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-frdx5b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fasync-autocomplete%2Fasync-autocomplete.component.ts 
You need to click on "Load books" so the AsyncAutocompleteComponent trigger the store, and then display the list of book in a select.
(and sorry for the delay I didn't have a computer with me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [here is a forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-adtzkl) that shows the correct way to handle event and data flow.

**As I mentioned in my comment, passing observables and subscriptions into components is an anti-pattern.** Doing this should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

I am going to just post the pieces of code that are different than what you show above...

When you need to trigger something in a parent component, use an `@Output`, rather than passing a subscription.

```
  @Input({ required: true }) searchValues: Book[] | null = [];

  @Input({ required: true }) fieldCtrl!: FormControl<any | null>; // form control to return the selected value

  @Output() loadBooks = new EventEmitter();
```

Then this component should handle the async binding for the data, so that change detection is run for the async-autocomplete component whenever the data changes. Also, the there is a new event handler for when the button is pressed, which calls the load in the store.

```
<p>Select a book :</p>
<app-async-autocomplete
  [searchValues]="searchValues$ | async"
  (loadBooks)="onLoadBooks()"
  [fieldCtrl]="fieldCtrl"
></app-async-autocomplete>
```

The load function effect you wrote also needed some adjustments. There really is no need to use an `exhaustMap` and then a `switchMap`. I recommend using either `combineLastestWith` from `rxjs` or the `concatLatestFrom` found in the [`@ngrx/operators` library](https://ngrx.io/guide/operators/operators#concatlatestfrom) when you need to unwrap observables while processing an effect.

```
  readonly loadBooks = this.effect<void>((trigger$) =>
    trigger$.pipe(
      tap((_) => console.log('fetch books')),
      combineLatestWith(this.userInstance$, this.selectedCompanyId$),
      switchMap(([_, instance, selectedCompanyId]) => {
        if (instance && selectedCompanyId) {
          return this._booksHttpService.getBooks().pipe(
            tapResponse(
              (newBooks) => {
                console.log('newBooks=');
                console.table(newBooks);
                this.patchState({
                  books: newBooks,
                });
              },
              (error: HttpErrorResponse) => console.error(error)
            )
          );
        }
        return [];
      })
    )
  );
```

Please see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-adtzkl) to see how it all works together.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand, the goal is to really keep AsyncAutocompleteComponent "dumb" :) 
And thanks for the operators improvement too !
But I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :/
Thanks you again and have a nice day !